# Jquery Undo last change to DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, undo

What is the easiest way to undo last change done to Dom. let's say i appended an image or div  or we made changes to any of the elements and i want to undo the last thing that affected the dom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clone previously the container and then to undo just have to clean the container and put the dom cloned.

http://api.jquery.com/clone/
http://api.jquery.com/empty

Comment: Nice idea, but that means if i want to remove the last added element, i have to remove both the original and clone. it's kinda redundant

Comment: first clones the DOM in the current state, then by adding new DOM elements is a new, if you want to undo, delete the current DOM and insert the old, or the method 'html()' in a single step '$(container).html(cloned)'

Comment: No i meant if i wanted to delete original element, then i have to delete both original and cloned.

Comment: @Alex, sorry I do not understand, can you put an example

Comment: No worries, i got what you are saying.